# Review should allow for rereviewing an incorrect click

Tags: feature-request

I just reviewed something and clicked the wrong button by accident.  Hitting the back button, I can see my selection but I cannot edit it.  There should be a duration (a minute?) in which you can edit your selection.

Comment: Meh.  If it's an honest mistake it's no big deal.  Just try to be careful in the future.  Then the SO devs don't have to worry about "pending" review judgments.

Comment: Wouldn't that fundamentally break things like review audits?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, how so? After a minute it would be locked in.  This just allows for an inadvertent click.

Comment: I think @ryanyuyu means that if it is just a one time accident, just deal with it and move on. One misclick won't kill you.

Comment: Why are we optimizing for corner cases?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, this isn't an optimization, it is dealing with it.  Doesn't have to be top priority.

Comment: @mmking, of course it'll not kill me, but it could cause something to occur that wasn't the intent as in being the tipping point for if something gets in or chucked out.

Comment: What particular action you are concerned about? I don't think there are irreversible actions - and for most you can act yourself immediately/shortly. I.e. if it is rejected or approved edit - suggest/make opposite when current is settled, close/open vote - retract,...

Comment: Not so much of a big deal I guess if it was accepted.  However, if a review is rejected, and it is the tipping point.  Does it get wiped from the DB?  If so, then the information is lost.  If not, then yeah, I guess it could be retrieved and put back.  However, does the editor's 'points' get modified with an acception/rejection?

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty useless feature to have since you can go to the question directly and fix your wrong review in most cases.

For example, if you clicked on "Looks OK" or "No Action Needed" by accident when you really meant to edit something, you can just hit the back button, click on the link to the question, and then go edit the question regularly instead of in the queue.

If you clicked on "Looks OK" or "No Action Needed" when you meant to flag or recommend deletion, you can then just flag the post directly to help make up for your error.

If you clicked on "Approve" for the suggested edit when you meant reject you can go back to the post and rollback the edit.

Now, lets say you accidentally clicked on "reject" for a suggested edit when you meant approve. If you end up rejecting the edit, it wasn't a simple misclick since you have to select a reason for rejection (or place an edit yourself if reject and improve) , so you would have needed to misclick at least twice .. which really no one has any sympathy for.